# Optimizing code for matching 2 values on 2 sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have a customer list on Sheet1 and raw data on Sheet2. There over 40 customer groups and i was wondering if there is a more efficient way handle this other than setting `For` for each of groups.

The customer list is on C row. For example group A is from C2:C25, group B is C26:C89, group C is C90:C116 and so on.

The goal of this code is to figure out if any of client groups are in raw data on Sheet2 (which is over 14k rows in column A) and to show, pref. with a single `MsgBox`, that they are.

```
Sub shomedawau()
Dim FindString As String
Dim Rng As Range

For Each Cell In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2:C32")
    FindString = Cell.Value

    If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
        With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A")
            Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox "group A found"
            End If
        End With
    End If
Next

For Each Cell In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C33")
    FindString = Cell.Value

    If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
        With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A")
            Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox "group B found"
            End If
        End With
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Try to replace `Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A")` with `Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A10000")` or other fixed value to test if it would work faster (it should). Than you can replace that fixed range with range from first to last non-zero cell.

Comment: If you had a list of each group and the relevant range alongside you could use another loop.

Comment: @SJR The list are on C row. For example group A is from C2:C25, group B is C26:C89, group C is C90:C116 and so on.

Comment: OK so if you have that in a two-column table in your file somewhere you could loop through each row.

Comment: I wonder how many cells there are to loop through in `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C33")`. I also wonder what the fun would be to have 39 messages of "Group A found" and no message for the remaining one which wasn't found. Perhaps the code might be made more efficient so much easier if it were known what it tries to achieve.

Comment: Agreed. As I mentioned before searching in whole range probably jeopardizes run-time.

Comment: @Variatus added more explanation, hopes it clarifies what i want it to do.

Comment: So, group A is in Sheet1!C2:C25 and in C26 the next group starts. How might one determine where one group ends and the next group starts?

Comment: I do. Sheet1 is static, so i can just set up in what range is group A, B, C and so on.

Comment: Don't understand. Is it the group you look for in raw data or the individual customer? `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2:C32")` confuses me. Are these 31 customers? Or 31 groups? And how can you arrive at the message "group A found" if you looked for a customer name? Why would it not be any other group?

Comment: @Variatus [It looks something like that.](https://imgur.com/nt5ogxU)

Comment: Which one is column C? (with matching names in Sheet2!A:A)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163865/discussion-between-artur-albert-hamelak-and-variatus).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should actually run pretty quickly. However, there is a place for optiomization, if you disregard the ranges and start working with arrays:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim r1      As Variant
    Dim r2      As Variant
    Dim r       As Variant
    Dim result  As Variant

    r1 = Application.Transpose(Worksheets(1).Range("C1:C10"))
    r2 = Application.Transpose(Worksheets(2).Range("A:A")) 'up to 65536th row!

    For Each r In r1
        result = Application.Match(r, r2, 0)
        If Not IsError(result) Then
            Debug.Print r & " is found!"
        End If
    Next r

End Sub
```

The code reads the two ranges only once and after this it operates in the VBA environment, which is significantly faster.

[MSDN WorksheetFunciton.Match](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-match-method-excel)

Comment: Did you actually time your suggestion? OP doesn't read anything from the worksheet. Hence no time saved by transferring to an array. He might use `Match` directly on the worksheet if it is deemed faster than `Find`.

Comment: @Variatus - what do you think this is - `For Each Cell In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C33")` or this - `After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count)`? Where are the values coming from?

Comment: I'm having an issue that even tho customer from `r1` is not in data from `r2` it still shows as found and I have no idea why is that.

Comment: @Vityata and what if r1 is a single cell insted of range?

Comment: @ArturAlbertHamelak - with `r1` as a single range the loop should iterate just once, so it should be ok.

Comment: @Vityata getting error when 13 type mismatch when running `r1 = Application.Transpose(Worksheets(1).Range("C33"))` . Furthermore what how can i copy result into another sheet?

Comment: @ArturAlbertHamelak - if it is one cell, do it like this: `r1 = Worksheets(1).Range("C33")`. To copy the result to another sheet something like this should be doable - `Worksheets(2).Range("A1:A10") = Worksheets(1).Range("B1:B10")`

Comment: @ArturAlbertHamelak - how is `r1` declared? Just this line - `r1 = Worksheets(1).Range("C33")` should not give you an error.

Comment: @Vityata `Dim r2 As Variant` and `r2 = Worksheets(1).Range("C33")` and before r2 is r1 as `r1 = Application.Transpose(Worksheets(1).Range("C2:C32"))`

Comment: @ArturAlbertHamelak - this 4 lines give you error 13? https://pastebin.com/n93ccMG7

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163949/discussion-between-artur-albert-hamelak-and-vityata).

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code. However, before you do check the enumerations at the top. That is where you can determine which column is which in which sheet. Change as required. And, BTW, `Enums` must be at the top of the code sheet before any procedures.

You will also need to change the names of the two worksheets. I called the "RawData" and "Groups". Replace these names with those in your workbook.

And, finally, I presumed that the group names, which I had to presume that they are in column B (change the enum to match the fact) are located in merged cells. The code won't work if they are not. (Can be tweaked if necessary.) It will also not work if RawData!A1 is a horizontally merged cell.

```
Option Explicit

Enum Nsg                        ' Sheet "Groups"
    ' 25 Jan 2018
    NsgFirstDataRow = 2
    NsgGroup = 2                ' 2 = column B
    NsgCustom
End Enum

Enum Nsd                        ' Sheet "Data"
    ' 25 Jan 2018
    NsdFirstDataRow = 2
    NsdCustom = 1               ' 1 = column A
End Enum


Sub FindGroups()
    ' 25 Jan 2018

    Dim Msg As String
    Dim Spike As String                         ' result collector
    Dim ArrCustom As Variant
    Dim SearchRng As Range
    Dim R As Long, Rstart As Long, Rend As Long
    Dim Rc As Long                              ' Customers

    With Worksheets("RawData")
        R = .Cells(.Rows.Count, NsdCustom).End(xlUp).Row
        Set SearchRng = Range(.Cells(NsdFirstDataRow, NsdCustom), _
                              .Cells(R, NsdCustom))
    End With

    With Worksheets("Groups")
        ArrCustom = Range(.Cells(1, NsgCustom), _
                          .Cells(.Rows.Count, NsgCustom).End(xlUp))
        R = NsgFirstDataRow
        Do While R <= UBound(ArrCustom)
            Rstart = R
            Rend = Rstart + .Cells(R, NsgGroup).MergeArea.Rows.Count - 1
            R = Rend + 1
            For Rc = Rstart To Rend
                If FindCustomer(ArrCustom(Rc, 1), SearchRng) Then
                    Spike = Spike & Chr(13) & .Cells(Rstart, NsgGroup).Value
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next Rc
        Loop
    End With

    Msg = IIf(Len(Spike), "The following", "No")
    MsgBox Msg & " groups were found in the raw data." & Spike, _
           vbInformation, "Search report"
End Sub

Private Function FindCustomer(ByVal Custom As String, _
                              SearchRng As Range) As Boolean
    ' 25 Jan 2018

    Dim Fnd As Range

    With SearchRng
        Set Fnd = .Find(What:=Custom, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
    End With
    FindCustomer = Not (Fnd Is Nothing)
End Function
```